# What happen when a process request more memory than available?

Tags: memory-management

What happen when a process try to allocate more memory than available memory (including virtual memory) ? will that process crash?

Comment: The answer to this question depends a lot on the programming language and operating system used.

Comment: On Windows you'll probably see a "Windows is running low on memory" message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the language. A C malloc() will return NULL, which many programs ignore, so the likelihood of a crash (SIGSEGV) is quite high. A C++ program should throw an exception, which at worst should cause a orderly exit of the program. A Java program ditto. There are many other languages and many other behaviours of course.

Comment: Not always. Linux is known to overcommit memory by default (search for "linux memory overcommit" on Google).